# How to insert data from Excel into a temp table in Spark SQL

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-zeppelin

I have a list of about 12,000 user id's in an excel spreadsheet and I want to insert them into a temp table in SQL. I know there are a lot of different ways to do this in SQL Server etc., but I'm working in Zeppelin /Apache Spark SQL and I'm not familiar with a quick way of doing this.

The excel data looks like this:

```
userid
014
020
055
101
151
175
...
12000
```

I was trying to do something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE user.temp_excel_import (userid string)
```

...

```
INSERT INTO TABLE user.temp_excel_import
VALUES
('014'),
('020'),
('055'),...
```

Is this something that can be done efficiently in Zeppelin or would I need to do some manipulation in Excel before I paste into Zeppelin?

Comment: You can use https://github.com/crealytics/spark-excel to read the excel data as dataframe and register as a table

Comment: have you tried reading this as csv?

Answer (score 0):

Read your file as CSV.

When you have your DataFrame use `createOrReplaceTempView` and you will be able to query it.

Example in Zeppelin with a random DataFrame:

[image]